# Getting group by sum and total sum in a single query when joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I Have 2 tables and would like the sum total of multiple expenses
For each employee ID, hope my example will better explain the result I'm trying to achieve

Employee Table:

```
Emp_ID  EmpName  EmpSrname

1001    John     Wilkes
1002    Sandra   Minotaur
1003    Dante    Inferno
```

Expenses Table:

```
Emp_ID  Expense_Name  Ammount

1001    Lunch         25
1002    Drinks        55
1003    Hotel         120
1001    Dinner        80
1001    Breakfast     20
1002    LineDancing   15
1002    Dinner        80
```

Looking for the total sum of each Emp_Id for food expenses by having a total for (Lunch, Breakfast, Dinner)

Here is what the expected result should look like:

```
Emp_ID  EmpName  EmpSrname  TotalFood
1001    John     Wilkes     125
1002    Sandra   Minotaur   80
```

Comment: how is 1001 has 125?

Comment: join and simple group by would do

Comment: How are you getting `125` for `1001`?  In your data it should only be `45`...

Comment: your edit breaks my output of my answer, but it was correct for the first version you supplied.

Answer (score 2):

This does the job with a simple join and some aggregation but produces different output to your desired output:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
    ([Emp_ID] int, [EmpName] varchar(6), [EmpSrname] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO #Employee
    ([Emp_ID], [EmpName], [EmpSrname])
VALUES
    (1001, 'John', 'Wilkes'),
    (1002, 'Sandra', 'Minotaur'),
    (1003, 'Dante', 'Inferno')
;


CREATE TABLE #Expenses
    ([Emp_ID] int, [Expense_Name] varchar(11), [Amount] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Expenses
    ([Emp_ID], [Expense_Name], [Amount])
VALUES
    (1001, 'Lunch', 25),
    (1002, 'Drinks', 55),
    (1003, 'Hotel', 120),
    (1002, 'Dinner', 80),
    (1001, 'Breakfast', 20),
    (1002, 'LineDancing', 15)
;

SELECT em.Emp_ID ,
       em.EmpName ,
       em.EmpSrname ,
       sum(ex.Amount ) Total 
FROM #Employee em INNER JOIN #Expenses ex ON ex.Emp_ID = em.Emp_ID
WHERE ex.Expense_Name IN ('Lunch','Breakfast','Dinner')
GROUP BY em.Emp_ID ,
         em.EmpName ,
         em.EmpSrname

DROP TABLE #Employee
DROP TABLE #Expenses
```

**Produces:**

```
Emp_ID  EmpName EmpSrname   Total
1001    John    Wilkes      45
1002    Sandra  Minotaur    80
```

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN`, filter and aggregate like this:

```
select 
    e.emp_id, e.empName, e.EmpSrName, sum(x.amount) totalfood
from employee e
inner join expenses x
on e.emp_id = x.emp_id
where x.expense_name in ('Lunch','Breakfast','Dinner')
group by e.emp_id, e.empName, e.EmpSrName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
Select  E.Emp_Id, E.EmpName, E.EmpSrname, 
        Sum(X.Ammount) As TotalFood
From    Employee    E
Join    Expenses    X   On  X.Emp_Id = E.Emp_Id
                        And X.Expense_Name In ('Breakfast', 'Lunch', 'Dinner')
Group By E.Emp_Id, E.EmpName, E.EmpSrname
```

Note, your desired results don't match your data.  Based on the sample data these should be the results:

```
Emp_ID  EmpName  EmpSrname  TotalFood
1001    John     Wilkes     45
1002    Sandra   Minotaur   80
```